# How to install multiple Recipes in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, recipe

I have installed `b2b_b2c_acc recipe` and I need to work on `oms`(Order management ) few have suggested me to `install b2c_acc_oms` have some set of extenstions releate to order management. if I install `b2c_acc_oms recipe` will this recipe overrides the previous one ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will override it. 
You can manually add b2c_acc_oms extensions to your extensions.xml file on your config folder then ant clean all.

Answer (score 0):

> If I install b2c_acc_oms recipe will this recipe override the previous
>   one?

Yes, It will override previously installed recipe.

You have to manually add `b2c_acc_oms` extensions to your `localextensions.xml` file, to identify list of extensions, you can refer `build.gradle` file (`installer/recipes/b2c_acc_oms/build.gradle`)

```
    extName 'ldap'
    extName 'virtualjdbc'
    extName 'springintegrationlibs'
    extName 'hmc'
    extName 'voucher'
    extName 'platformhmc'
    extName 'promotions'
    extName 'customerreview'
    extName 'backoffice'
    extName 'cockpit'
    extName 'admincockpit'
    extName 'reportcockpit'
    extName 'productcockpit'
    extName 'solrfacetsearch'
    extName 'basecommerce'
    extName 'cms2'
    extName 'cms2lib'
    extName 'btg'
    extName 'ticketsystem'
    extName 'payment'
    extName 'cmscockpit'
    extName 'solrfacetsearchhmc'
    extName 'commerceservices'
    extName 'commercewebservicescommons'
    extName 'acceleratorservices'
    extName 'acceleratorcms'
    extName 'yacceleratorcore'
    extName 'commercefacades'
    extName 'acceleratorfacades'
    extName 'addonsupport'
    extName 'acceleratorstorefrontcommons'
    extName 'yacceleratorfacades'
    extName 'commercesearch'
    extName 'commercesearchhmc'
    extName 'acceleratorwebservicesaddon'
    extName 'yaddon'
    extName 'yacceleratorinitialdata'
    extName 'apparelstore'
    extName 'yacceleratorstorefront'
    extName 'cscockpit'
    extName 'yacceleratorcockpits'
    extName 'instore'
    extName 'electronicsstore'
    extName 'warehousingbackoffice'
    extName 'warehousing'
    extName 'yacceleratorordermanagement'
    extName 'customersupportbackoffice'
    extName 'platformbackoffice'
    extName 'solrserver'
    extName 'ordermanagementaddon'
    extName 'warehousingwebservices'
    extName 'warehousingfacade'
    extName 'ordermanagementwebservices'
    extName 'ordermanagementfacade'
```

Install Addon :

```
ordermanagementaddon
```